# In standard detail page custom button if condition true the button wants to open Jquery popup and condition false the button opens VF page directly

Tags: javascript, custom-button

On Standard detail page I have custom button with execute javascript functionality, based on the condition true the button want opens a jQuery popup with another VF page and the condition false the button will open the Direct Visual force page. Please some one help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this as the javascript for the button. Just change the condition, apexpages, Ttitle,etc in what you want.

```
if ({!Account.Phone}=='123') {
openPopupFocusEscapePounds('/apex/apexpage1','Title',1024,768,'width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no','false','false');
} else {
window.top.location='/apex/apexpage2';
}
```

It's pretty much self explanatory.
If you want to use jquery, that is a different story, but I don't see why you would need that. Maybe you have some requirements that warrants the use of jQuery?

Comment: Thanks you so much, your suggestion is great but I am using jQuery popup,

Comment: Yes I have a requirements that I should use the jQuery for very nice UI and also freez the background.